# Intellij Android Junit test Asserttrue message output location

Tags: android, junit, intellij-idea

When i run the following code, it should output the text 'Did match' somewhere:

```
Assert.assertTrue("TeDid match" + ed.getText().toString(), ed.getText().toString().equals("55"));
```

But i can't find out where it exactly outputs.

I cant find the message in the android log, run log.

Really confusing.

Where does it actually output?

Answer (score 0):

1. It outputs only when the assertion fails.
2. If you really try to advance in TDD (Test driven development) you shouldn't need an output from the assertion as the Test function already tells what's wrong.

But if you still want to have an output if the assertion fails try using the `assertEquals()` Method as a static method of the `Junit Framework`:

```
assertEquals(String message, String expected, String result);
```

The output appears in the 'Run' section of IntelliJ.